# React useEffect doesn't dispatch the redux action after page refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, react-state-management

I'm trying to render the data from the following object of data which is coming from an API.

```
{
    "code": 0,
    "c": "verified",
    "d": "verified",
    "leaseInfo": {
        "infoId": 6
    },
    "cpfPrice": "500.00",
    "carCurrentLocation": {
        "id": 1,
        "carId": "df47a56a395a49b1a5d06a58cc42ffc4"
    },
    "n": "verified",
    "p": "false",
    "ownerCarInfo": {
        "brand": "Ferrari",
        "model": "0"
    },
    "serviceFeeRate": 0.10,
    "depositPrice": "100.00",
    "pics": [
        {
            "picid": 49,
            "carId": "df47a56a395a49b1a5d06a58cc42ffc4"
        },
    ],
    "items": {
        "itemid": 5,
        "carId": "df47a56a395a49b1a5d06a58cc42ffc4"
    }
}
```

I'm using `react-redux` to dispatch an action, where I will be provided with the data under a state named '`carDetails`'.

However, when I try to access the data, if my component is refreshed, `carDetails` becomes `undefined` and hence gives "`Cannot read property ownerCarInfo of undefined.`"

I'm obtaining and de-structuring the data of `carDetails` like this in my React component:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const CarInfo = ({ match }) => {

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const details = useSelector((state) => state.carDetails);

const { loading, carDetails } = details;
const {pics, carCurrentLocation, items, ownerCarInfo} = carDetails;

useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getCarDetails(match.params.id));
}, [dispatch, match]);

return (
   <div>
  {loading ? (
    <Loader></Loader>
  ) : (
    <>
      <p>{d.depositPrice}</p>
      <p>{ownerCarInfo.brand}</p>
    </>
  )}
</div>
```

);
)

}

As long as the component or the `React` application is not refreshed, it retrieves data and displays it correctly. The `carDetails` becomes an empty array as soon as the page is refreshed.

This is the `getCarDetails()` action:

```
export const getCarDetails = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: CAR_DETAILS_REQUEST,
    });

    const { userLogin } = getState();
    const { userInfo } = userLogin;

    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: userInfo.token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };

    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `${BASE_API}/car/info/getDetails/${id}/${userInfo.bscId}`,
      config
    );

    dispatch({
      type: CAR_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: CAR_DETAILS_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.msg
          ? error.response.data.msg
          : error.msg,
    });
  }
};
```

This is my reducer:

```
export const carsDetailsReducer = (state = { carDetails: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CAR_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case CAR_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, carDetails: action.payload };
    case CAR_DETAILS_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is how I declare `carDetails` in the redux store.

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  carDetails: carsDetailsReducer,
});
```

What is the cause for `carDetails` becoming undefined and the `useEffect` not running on page refresh?

Comment: How you declare `carDetails ` in the redux store

Comment: @Viet I updated the code in the question. Please check.

Comment: Is everything fine with `getCarDetails` function?

Comment: @AmirhosseinEbrahimi I have added the function to the above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **`axios`** your action should look like this with **`async`** function and **`await`** while you are calling API.

If you are passing API car id in the `api` link then pass the `id` in the parameters:

```js
import axios from "axios";


export const loadData = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
       type: "CAR_DETAILS_REQUEST",
    });

  const detailData = await axios.get("http:\\****/id");

  dispatch({
    type: "CAR_DETAILS_SUCCESS",
    payload: {
     success: detailData.data,
    },
  });
};
```

**Reducer:**

```
    const initailState = { carDetails: [], loading: true };

export const carsDetailsReducer = (state = initailState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CAR_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return { ...state,
                loading: true
 };
    case CAR_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return {...state,
               loading: false,
               carDetails: action.payload 
};
    case CAR_DETAILS_FAIL:
      return { ...state,
               loading: false, 
               error: action.payload };
    default:
      return ...state;
  }
};
```

Your **useEffect** should only work when data is fetched:

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const CarInfo = ({ match }) => {

const dispatch = useDispatch();
const details = useSelector((state) => state.carDetails);

const { loading, carDetails } = details;
const {pics, carCurrentLocation, items, ownerCarInfo} = carDetails;

useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getCarDetails(id));
}, [dispatch]);

return (
   <div>
  {loading ? (
    <Loader></Loader>
  ) : (
    <>
      <p>{d.depositPrice}</p>
      <p>{ownerCarInfo.brand}</p>
    </>
  )}
</div>
```

You can also use it without a `useEffect` by making an **`onclick()`** function like this:

```
const loadDetailHandler = () => {
    dispatch(getCarDetails(id));
  };

return (
    <div onClick={loadDetailHandler} >
    </div>
```

Comment: This is the complete solution that ultimately worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `CAR_DETAILS_REQUEST`. You only return `{ loading: true };` so `carDetails` will be lost and become `undefined`.

Just update your reducer like this:

```
case CAR_DETAILS_REQUEST:
  return { ...state, loading: true };
```

Answer (score 1):

If `carDetails` initial state is an array, then why are you destructuring object properties from it in your UI? Question for another time...

If after reloading the page the state reverts back to the initial state, an empty array is still a defined object. You need to track down what is causing your `state.carDetails.carDetails` to become undefined. If you examine your reducer notice that your `CAR_DETAILS_REQUEST` case wipes the `carDetails` state out and it becomes `undefined`. Honestly I'm surprised you aren't seeing this issue when your code runs normally without a page reload.

You need to hold on to that state. For good measure, you should ***always*** shallow copy the existing state when computing the next state object unless you've good reason to omit parts of state.

```
export const carsDetailsReducer = (state = { carDetails: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CAR_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state, // <-- shallow copy existing state
        loading: true,
      };

    case CAR_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state, // <-- shallow copy existing state
        loading: false,
        carDetails: action.payload
      };

    case CAR_DETAILS_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state, // <-- shallow copy existing state
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a mistake which I realized after a while. I have been trying to de-structure from an array. However, shallow copying did help.

Answer (score 1):

for  me, I think  you should save  the  state  in the

```
 `case CAR_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state, // <-- shallow copy existing state
        loading: true,
      };
`
```

to be able to use it  before o when you want to use a reducer you should each  case
have  the  old state     the reducer return  the same  sharp of initial state that  put it  you also used is  loading and  that not found in the initial state
so  try  to  make  the  shape  of the state

```
state={
isloading:false,
 carDetails: []

}
```

also  try each time to same  the state by  `{...state ,is loading:true}`